# Angular. How to expand navigation menu programmatically

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a menu with navigation that is built with bootstrap in angular project. This menu has some levels of depth that are collapsed by default. What I have to do - autoexpand menu when the current path in angular application is changed.

```html
   <div class="menu-list">
       <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
         <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#list01Forms" class="collapsed rounded">
           <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Menu 1. <span class="arrow"></span>
         </li>
         <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="list01Forms">
           <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#list01Forms01" class="collapsed rounded">
             <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Menu 1.1 <span class="arrow"></span>
           </li>
           <ul class="sub-menu-sub-menu collapse" id="list01Forms01">
             <li [routerLink]="['path1']" [routerLinkActive]="' ... '">
             <li [routerLink]="['path2']" [routerLinkActive]="' ... '">
```

Thank you in advance!